# How to install Mailchimp in magento 2.1.5 from composer

Tags: magento-2.1, mailchimp

I am trying to install MailChimp in the following way but unfortunately, it did not work for me.

1. install the MailChimp library

> `composer require ebizmarts/mailchimp-lib`

2. Install MailChimp right version as per Magento version

> `composer require mailchimp/mc-magento2:100.1.37`

after that, I am running following command

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade

php bin/magento cache:clean

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy ar_SA
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_US en_GB
```

But above process did not help me.

Thanks for your support in advance.

Comment: try this :- composer require mailchimp/mc-magento2

Answer (score 2):

I got an answer to this question. I follow the below step

1. composer require ebizmarts/mailchimp-lib
2. check the composer version as per my Magento version. I am using magento2.1.5 for that I used *composer require mailchimp/mc-magento2:100.1.37*

   > https://github.com/mailchimp/mc-magento2/releases
3. php bin/magento setup:upgrade
4. php bin/magento setup:di:compile
5. php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
6. php bin/magento cache:flush

Answer (score 1):

Follow the manual installation guide,

1-install composer 
2-composer require mailchimp/mc-magento2  
3-Download 'Mailchimp for Magento2  
4-extract the contents in app/code/Ebizmarts/MailChimp  
5-run setup:upgrade 
6-run di:compile 
6-run cache:flush 
7-run indexer:reindex

Comment: Does this approach work for Magento CE 2.3.6 version as well?

Comment: yes it should work